# Display Arrays corresponding to the days of the current month

Tags: php, arrays, date

I seem to have stuck here with my logic. I have a set of 365 arrays and I want to display only the arrays that correspond to the days of the current month.

I am new to programming and I am taking the challenge of creating a monthly bible reading plan.

This are my arrays:

```
$meses = array(1 => 'Janeiro', 2 => 'Fevereiro', 3 => 'Março', 4 => 'Abril', 5 => 'Maio', 6 => 'Junho', 7 => 'Julho', 8 => 'Agosto', 9 => 'Setembro', 10 => 'Outubro', 11 => 'Novembro', 12 => 'Dezembro');

$leitura = array(
1 => array(
    'Antigo Testamento' => 'Gn 1,2',
    'Novo Testamento' => 'Mt 1,2'
),
2 => ...
);
```

If I fill all the arrays here it would be too long! :)

So I was wondering how I could make this happen. My question is, how can I tell PHP that "December" has 31 days and that it should display only the 31 arrays corresponding to the days of the year that make up December? And that it would then in January display only the 31 arrays that correspond to that month and so on?

Thank you so much!

Comment: How would you deal with February, which may change?

Comment: Hi @Farkie, I was actually thinking of leaving it as 28 default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
date('z');
```

to get the current day of the year. 
In case the year is a leap year, you can easily substract one if the year is a leap year, so

```
function daynumber() {
    $day = date('z');
    if ($day >= 60 AND date('L') == 1) $day = $day - 1;
    return $day;
}
```

This will result in the date number for February, 29th begin the same as February 28th.

That way you could display the array for the current day using `print_r($leitura[daynumber()]);`

If you want to print all arrays for the whole month, you could use something like

```
function arraysmonth() {
    $daynumber = $fisrtdayofmonth = date('z',strtotime("first day of this month"));
    $lastdayofmonth = date('z',strtotime("last day of this month"));
    while ($daynumber < $lastdayofmonth) {
        $returnarray[] = $leitura[$daynumber];
        $daynumber = $daynumber + 1;
    }
    return $returnarray;
}
print_r(arraysmonth());
```

Comment: Thanks!! Your answer has given me some ideas to work on. I really appreciate it!

Comment: If my answer has answered your question, would you mind to mark my answer as accepted. You can do this under the up- and downvote buttons.

Comment: Awesome, I just finished implementing your solution on my code. Thanks a lot!